# prestashop addons appear twice everywhere

Tags: prestashop

I am facing a weird problem with a prestashop 1.6.1.4 with the theme Supershop by Kutethemes.

On attached screenshots, you may notice that many addons are appearing twice (or more sometimes): top navigation links, languages and currencies on Home ; information links and filters block on any Category page.

I activated debug mode, but I don't understand every warnings. They are all about the theme and its addons.

Here are some debug mode warning on the front end:

- On category page:

  > Notice: Undefined index: HOOK_OVIC_CATEGORYSLIDER in /var/www/dev/cache/smarty/compile/91/38/9d/91389dd629887737f56184370db72d165b23ea28.file.category.tpl.php on line 41
  >
  > Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/dev/cache/smarty/compile/91/38/9d/91389dd629887737f56184370db72d165b23ea28.file.category.tpl.php on line 41
- on product page:

  > Notice: Undefined index: HOOK_OVIC_CATEGORYSIZECHART in /var/www/dev/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 880
  >
  > Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/dev/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 880

The tags on the product page are also messed up, including some I added to this product but also tags from other categories of products... I don't know if that is related or not.

I did not add any other addons than the ones provided, I did not edit the code, and I just filled the website with data (products, text, images...) and edited many configs and settings to suit my needs... I don't see what I did wrong. If someone could point me out what is going on, that would be really appreciated because I am begining to feel desperate !

[Screenshot1: home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHHSF.jpg) and
[Screenshot2: category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQbUS.jpg)

Comment: Debug mode warnings fixed (a Category Slider addon and a size chart addon were not installed, I installed them (even if I did not want to use them), and now the warnings disappeared).

Comment: Can you in `Advanced parameters > Performance > Disable all overrides` and check? And `> Disable non Prestashop modules` and check? Next steps depends.

Comment: `Disable all overrides` does not change anything (already tried earlier). When I activate `Disable non Prestashop modules` of course the whole website is bugged and empty, because the theme Supershop is based on custom modules.

Comment: Then are you sure you have installed your theme properly? Have you modified something manually? I guess this theme isn't done perfectly if you are getting these errors. Can you check in `Modules and services > Positions` - maybe these twice appearing modules are hooked into two different `hooks`, standing beside each other? You can try `Live edit` function for it too.

Comment: I wanted to use live edit, but the tool is not showing at all, and when the theme configurator module is activated, it adds CSS parts of default theme css6 like black background to the body... I already checked the modules hooks and the look fine. The duplicate code is inside the the div.div-display-nav so they are not coming from another hook position. Thank you for trying to help me, I hope we can find what is going on.